# Usability and distracting and confusing design

Tags: website-design, web

I have designed my theme here you can take a look :

[image: http://photontechs.com/themes/VSResume/Designer/]

Reviewer said "Nice idea, but usability for this conversion is pretty low. Theme is also very distracting and confusing too. "

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your theme has the following features:

1. Visible "loading" screen on first load (bar & percentage)
2. Tile based navigation (hover to see links)
3. Hamburger Menu event at desktop resolution
4. Animation/separation of menu when not being hovered?

The reviewer of your theme was commenting on how your design is not very accessible, and that it does not provide a solid user experience. However, it does look pretty/professional.

#### Key takeaways:

- Loading screens are out. Even if they're lightning fast, they make your website "feel" slow.
- Your tile based navigation makes it impossible to know how to navigate the site unless the user hovers over each square. Navigation should be visible from the get-go, users should not need to hunt for it.
- The animation, while cool, adds nothing to the website contextually. Because it doesn't add anything beneficial, it could potentially confuse users.
- Hamburger menu: while much more acceptable on mobile, most/all nav options should be visible from the start to decrease confusion and illuminate all options to the user up front.

#### Ending notes

If you did this, you have skill, but you need to ask yourself questions as you design. For example: When my user visits, what are they trying to accomplish? How can I make their goals easier/faster to accomplish and less confusing?

These are high level notes, and there are exceptions to them. I hope they're enough to get you started. If you have any questions/comments, please let me know.

Comment: +1 i will update my theme upon  your suggestion, and see what reviewer says.

Comment: Can you please let me know what do you think about this idea ? http://prntscr.com/8vnbql